# Writing a watchdog in Python

Tags: process, signals, monitoring, watchdog

I need to write a watchdog on Ubuntu LTS for a 3rd party network file transfer java program that dies for every 40 - 50 minutes of sustained network transfer @4MB/s.

I cannot modify that java program but it spawns via upstart.

My current watchdog is a busy wait:

```
while monitoring_enabled:
    begin_time = now()
    # query ps and /proc to see if it's there
    end_time = now()
    diff_time = end_time - begin_time
    if not diff_time > sleep_time:
        sleep(sleep_time - diff_time)
```

Since, "busy wait is bad", and this is eating up ~10% CPU, I was wondering if there's a better way of solving this:

1. Have a notification/event handling instead of polling.
   Note that I am not implying that any notification/event is fired when the process terminates but am asking if the OS can determine that the java program has died
2. Modify the upstart script that spawns the java program so that it restarts it if the process goes down?
3. A better solution?
   Perhaps something like [Python API library and shell utilities to monitor file system events](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/), but for linux processes

Answer (score 2):

[Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) - Python, spawns and controls processes, event notifications, xml-rpc api, good docs, good reviews

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script to run the program in a while loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
    java -jar offendingProgram.jar
done
```

Then bg the script from where ever you start it.